# Windows 10 - How to reset the network (firewall) permissions for an app so the OS prompts you upon next access?

Tags: windows, networking, permissions

Not talking about "how to change my network location".

When you first run an app, there is some kind of prompt that has some boxes.

How is this managed (is it per app path? what if I rename the path of a program?) and how can I reset it so I get to change it again if I think I've chosen the incorrect tick boxes?

I found an image of what I'm talking about:

[image: IMG:]

Is there a way to "delete" an entry so that Windows asks you again when appropriate?

Edit - I didn't originally realize this was a Firewall thing, this is probably a duplicate.

Comment: It will be helpful if you post a screen shot so we accurately know what you are looking at.

Comment: I'll try - I can't seem to get it to appear again, is the problem... I know this is an awful question at the moment. edit: I googled it, I can use someone else's screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing for Windows Defender Firewall is to Reset to Default settings. This is easier than trying to manage the individual pieces. Open Windows Defender (System Tray), then Firewall and Network Protection.

[image]

Comment: Resetting to Default will mean no applications are blocked from making outgoing connections, and therefore there will be no more notification popups like shown.

Comment: In a normal machine, this is not usually an issue because default settings are for normal operation for most people.